# Why doesn't bash free memory up from unnamed variables once it's done with them?

Tags: bash, memory

Consider this situation:

```bash
$ ps -p $$ -o %mem
%MEM
 0.0
$ echo $(head -c200M /dev/urandom) > /dev/null
# command finishes but memory hasn't been released:
$ ps -p $$ -o %mem
%MEM
 7.4
```

The moment I exit bash, I can see the memory instantly freed up. Why is this? And, is there a way to free the memory without exiting bash? Not that I really need to do this as I can just fork bash and then end that child, I am mostly curious why this happens.

Comment: Just to note, this isn't specific to `bash`. Most programs hold any allocated memory for life, rather than return it to the operating system early.

Comment: (I should say, programming language rather than program.)

Comment: Most likely `malloc` allocates memory from the heap, calling something like `brk` or `sbrk` to expand the process's memory if necessary, but `free` only makes the memory available for allocation by the same process without returning it to the OS.

Comment: (in general, on modern operating systems that use paging, the OS will figure out on its own that a given piece of memory isn't being accessed frequently and swap it out, if there's memory pressure enough that not everything can afford to stick around in physical memory at once).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this?

As Keith Thompson commented, typically `malloc` calls `brk` or `sbrk` expanding process memory, but `free` only makes "marks" the memory within `malloc` to be reused within the same process.

> is there a way to free the memory without exiting bash?

You can write a Bash built-in that will call `malloc_trim()` (and also could call `mallopt` with `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD` to decrease the threshold to release the memory), compile that built-in and call it within Bash shell.

> Why doesn't bash free memory up from unnamed variables once it's done with them?

I think it is typical that memory allocation for a process is greedy. Once a process receives some memory, they wouldn't want to release it, for two reasons - the "act" of allocating the memory for the process is CPU consuming and the process is not sure if it will receive the memory again after releasing. Bottom line memory allocation algorithms prefer to keep the memory once they receive it.

---

The following `malloc_trim.c` Bash builtin source code:

```
#include <config.h>
#include <loadables.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int malloc_trim_builtin(WORD_LIST *list) {
    int ret1 = malloc_trim(0);
    int ret2 = mallopt(M_TRIM_THRESHOLD, 0);
    printf("malloc_trim=%d mallopt=%d\n", ret1, ret2);
    return 0;
}
char *malloc_trim_doc[] = {"Short AA AA description.", (char *)NULL};
struct builtin malloc_trim_struct = {
    "malloc_trim", /* builtin name */
    malloc_trim_builtin, /* function implementing the builtin */
    BUILTIN_ENABLED, /* initial flags for builtin */
    malloc_trim_doc, /* array of long documentation strings. */
    "malloc_trim", /* usage synopsis; becomes short_doc */
    0 /* reserved for internal use */
};
```

Can be compiled with:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags bash) -I/usr/lib/bash -shared -o malloc_trim.o ./malloc_trim.c
```

After compilation, the following shell transcript is possible:

```
$ ps -p $$ -o %mem
%MEM
 0.0
$ echo $(head -c50M /dev/urandom) > /dev/null
# null byte bla bla
$ ps -p $$ -o %mem
%MEM
 0.6
$ enable -f ./malloc_trim.o malloc_trim
$ malloc_trim
malloc_trim=1 mallopt=1
$ ps -p $$ -o %mem
%MEM
 0.0
```